# python-daemon 2.0.5 won't install with pip

Tags: python, pip, python-daemon

I am getting errors when trying to install python-daemon 2.0.5 with pip & python 2.6. I know there are other questions that refer to python-daemon 2.0.3 having this problem. But those answers indicate it should be fixed now.

I've tried installing older versions as well without luck. Although if I start over with a fresh virtualenv I am able to install 1.5.6 . However in this virtualenv I get the same error with 2.0.5 and 1.5.6

```
(py26)[brianb@api proj]$ pip install python-daemon
Downloading/unpacking python-daemon
 Downloading python-daemon-2.0.5.tar.gz (71Kb): 71Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-daemon
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/brianb/py26/build/python-daemon/setup.py", line 26, in     <module>
        import version
      File "version.py", line 438
        for item in versions}
      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/brianb/py26/build/python-daemon/setup.py", line 26, in <module>

    import version

  File "version.py", line 438

    for item in versions}

  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/brianb/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in a `py26` environment.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my problem, I was using an old virtualenv that had pip 1.0.2 , I upgraded virtualenv on the machine, created a new environment and that received pip 6.0.8 which was able to install python-daemon fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange! I tried to upgrade virtualenv too, but this did not work out.

To get it running, I had to upgrade to Python 2.7.